# Chapter template

Tags: formatting, chapters

What I want:

[image: What I want]

What I already have:

[image: What I already have]

Can someone help me to recreate this kind of chapter heading (first pic)?
All help is welcome!

Code for the second picture:

```
\documentclass[
      11pt,a4paper,twoside,openright]{book}
%nummering
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\pagestyle{plain}
\lhead{}
\chead{}
\rhead{}
\lfoot{}
\cfoot{\thepage}
\rfoot{}
\usepackage[dutch]{babel}
\usepackage[babel=true]{csquotes}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[explicit]{titlesec}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{charter}

\definecolor{mybluei}{RGB}{5, 0, 100}
\definecolor{myblueii}{RGB}{0, 0, 100}
\usepackage{titlesec}

\newcommand\ChapterFont{\rmfamily\selectfont\huge}
\newcommand\SectionFont{\bfseries\rmfamily\selectfont\Large}
 \titleformat{\chapter}[display]
 {\normalfont\ChapterFont\huge\color{myblueii}}
 {}
 {0pt}
 {\parbox[b]{0pt}{\mbox{}}%
    \parbox[b]{70 pt}{\colorbox{mybluei}{%
            \parbox[b][60pt][t]{60pt}{\centering%
                \color{white}%
                {\itshape\rmfamily\small\chaptertitlename}%
                \vfill{\fontsize{70}{70}\selectfont\thechapter}%
            }%
        }%
    }\hspace{15pt}%
    \parbox[b]{\dimexpr\textwidth}{%
        \raggedright\bfseries#1\vskip18pt%
    }%
 }

 \titleformat{name=\chapter,numberless}[display]
 {\normalfont\selectfont\huge\color{myblueii}}
 {}
 {0pt}
 {\parbox[b]{70pt}{\mbox{}}%
    \hspace{15pt}%
    \parbox[b]{\dimexpr\textwidth-15pt}{%
        \raggedright\bfseries#1\vskip6pt%
    }%
 }
 \titleformat{\section}
 {\normalfont\small\sffamily\SectionFont\color{myblueii}}
 {\colorbox{mybluei}{%
        \parbox[c][16pt][c]{40pt}{%
            \centering\textcolor{white}{\SectionFont\Large\rmfamily\thesection}%
        }%
    }%
 }
 {1em}
 {#1}
 [\vspace{-0.755\baselineskip}%
 \color{myblueii}\hspace*{\dimexpr40pt+2\fboxsep\relax}%
 \rule{\dimexpr\textwidth-40pt-2\fboxsep\relax}{1pt}%
 ]

 \usepackage{amsmath, amsthm, amssymb, amsfonts, enumerate, dlfltxbcodetips}
 \renewcommand{\qedsymbol}{$\blacksquare$}
```

Comment: Normally, on this site, the first person to offer help is the questioner, him- or herself.  This is done by providing an [minimal example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228/8528) (or see [here](http://www.tex.ac.uk/cgi-bin/texfaq2html?label=minxampl)), which lets the potential helpers get started.  As it is, your question leaves many important details about your assumptions and requirements left unstated.

Answer (score 11):

An option (providing settings for both numbered and unnumbered chapters); adjust the settings according to your needs:

```
\documentclass[openany]{book}
\usepackage[dutch]{babel}
\usepackage[explicit]{titlesec}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{lmodern}% to have a large font size for the chapter numbers
\usepackage{lipsum}% just to generate text for the example

\definecolor{chapnumberbg}{RGB}{26,40,105}
\definecolor{chapname}{RGB}{100,117,158}

\titleformat{\chapter}[display]
  {\normalfont}
  {}
  {0pt}
  {%
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \node[
      draw=chapname,
      rounded corners,
      outer sep=0pt,
      inner sep=6pt,
      rotate=90,
      line width=1pt,
      font=\Large\color{chapnumberbg}\bfseries
      ]
      (chapname) 
      {\chaptertitlename};
    \node[
      fill=chapnumberbg,
      minimum width=2cm,
      minimum height=2.3cm,
      rounded corners,
      anchor=west,
      font=\color{white}\fontsize{40}{48}\selectfont\bfseries
      ]
      at ([xshift=6pt]chapname.south)
      (chapnumber)
      {\thechapter};
    \node[
      anchor=west,
      text width=\textwidth-4cm,
      font=\bfseries\LARGE
      ] 
      at ([xshift=10pt]chapnumber.east)
      {#1};
    \fill[
      overlay,
      draw=none,
      line width=0pt,
      rounded corners=1pt,
      left color=chapnumberbg,
      right color=chapnumberbg!10
      ]
      ([yshift=-3pt]chapname.north west) rectangle ++(\textwidth,-3pt);  
    \end{tikzpicture}%
  }
\titleformat{name=\chapter,numberless}[display]
  {\normalfont}
  {}
  {0pt}
  {%
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \node[
      anchor=west,
      inner sep=0pt,
      outer sep=0pt,
      text width=\textwidth,
      font=\bfseries\LARGE
      ]
      (chaptitle) 
      {#1};
    \fill[
      overlay,
      draw=none,
      line width=0pt,
      rounded corners=1pt,
      left color=chapnumberbg,
      right color=chapnumberbg!10
      ]
      ([yshift=-3pt]chaptitle.south west) rectangle ++(\textwidth,-3pt);  
    \end{tikzpicture}%
  }

\begin{document}

\chapter{Test numbered chapter}
\lipsum[1-2]
\chapter{Test unnumbered chapter}
\lipsum[1-2]

\end{document}
```

An image of the resulting document:

[image]

A zoomed-in image for the numbered chapter:

[image]

A zoomed-in image for the unnumbered chapter:

[image]

To control the vertical positioning of the titles. you can use something like

```
\titlespacing*{\chapter} 
  {0pt}{20pt}{40pt}
```

The third mandatory argument (with a value of `20pt` in my example) controls the distance before the title and the fourth argument (with a value of `40pt` in my example) controls the distance after the title. Change those lengths to the desired value.

Comment: How can I do it manually (not link with chapter) ?

Answer (score 2):

A solution using the `tcolorbox` package (I touched only upon numbered chapters format). Btw, you chapterstyle should be `block`, not `display`:

```
\documentclass[
      11pt,a4paper,twoside,openright]{book}
%nummering
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\pagestyle{plain}
\lhead{}
\chead{}
\rhead{}
\lfoot{}
\cfoot{\thepage}
\rfoot{}
\usepackage[dutch]{babel}
\usepackage[babel=true]{csquotes}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[explicit]{titlesec}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{charter}

\definecolor{mybluei}{RGB}{5, 0, 100}
\definecolor{myblueii}{RGB}{0, 0, 100}
\usepackage{rotating, graphicx}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\newcommand\ChapterFont{\rmfamily\selectfont\huge}
\newcommand\SectionFont{\bfseries\rmfamily\selectfont\Large}

\titleformat{\chapter}[block]
 {\normalfont\ChapterFont\huge\color{myblueii}}%\raisebox{-0.6\height}
 {\tcbset{colframe=mybluei, boxrule=0.8pt, left=0pt, right=0pt, top=0pt, bottom=0pt}\raisebox{-0.48\height}{\rotatebox{90}{\tcbox[boxsep=4pt, colback= white ]{\color{mybluei}\Large\chaptertitlename}}}\hskip 0.25em\mbox{\tcbox[ boxsep=12pt, colback=mybluei, tcbox raise = -35pt]{\color{white}\bfseries\fontsize{70}{70}\selectfont\thechapter}}}
 {0.5em}
 {#1\vskip0.6ex\endgraf\titlerule[1ex]}[]

 \titleformat{name=\chapter,numberless}[block]
 {\normalfont\selectfont\huge\color{myblueii}}
 {}
 {0pt}
 {\parbox[b]{70pt}{\mbox{}}%
 \hspace{15pt}%
 \parbox[b]{\dimexpr\textwidth-15pt}{%
 \raggedright\bfseries#1\vskip6pt%
 }%
 }
 \titleformat{\section}
 {\normalfont\small\sffamily\SectionFont\color{myblueii}}
 {\colorbox{mybluei}{%
        \parbox[c][16pt][c]{40pt}{%
            \centering\textcolor{white}{\SectionFont\Large\rmfamily\thesection}%
        }%
    }%
 }
 {1em}
 {#1}
 [\vspace{-0.755\baselineskip}%
 \color{myblueii}\hspace*{\dimexpr40pt+2\fboxsep\relax}%
 \rule{\dimexpr\textwidth-40pt-2\fboxsep\relax}{1pt}%
 ]
  \usepackage{amsmath, amsthm, amssymb, amsfonts, enumerate}%, dlfltxbcodetips
 \renewcommand{\qedsymbol}{$\blacksquare$}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\chapter{Vectorruimtem}
\lipsum[1]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: @Gonzalo Medina: I simply meant that the style  that corresponds to the O.P.'s attempt is block, rather than display.